# How do I configure webpack to display react component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, configuration

So I'm trying to get my node project to render a simple react component, I'm using webpack for bundling

my package.json set's main entry point  as webpack.config.js and has  a srcipt  to run webpack-dev-server. Here  is my package.json :

```
{
"name": "@ruler-mobility/ruler",
"_comment": "main set to webpack's bundle file(home.tsx). this attr only explain main's purpose, delete it in the next merge ",
"main": "webpack.config.js",
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "chalk": "^3.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "geolocation-utils": "^1.2.2",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "query-string": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "typecast": "0.0.1",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/compression": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/errorhandler": "^0.0.32",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.15.14",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.25",
    "@types/numeral": "0.0.26",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/ts-nameof": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.18.0",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-autofix": "0.0.9",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-no-use-extend-native": "^0.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-imports-es6-autofix": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-switch-case": "^1.1.2",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.4",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-nameof": "^4.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://bitbucket.org/ruler-mobility/ruler.git"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "lint": "eslint . --quiet --fix --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx",
    "test": "jest --forceExit --coverage --verbose",
    "watch-test": "npm run test -- --watchAll",
    "stop-win": "Taskkill /IM node.exe /F",
    "stop-linux": "killall node"
},
"version": "1.0.0"
 }
```

my webpack.config.js  sets Home.tsx as entry point for the what to bundle and the  output  file's path in a  parent folder. here is how it looks:

```
const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
 const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
 const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
 const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
 const tsNameof = require('ts-nameof');
 const { PORT } = process.env;

module.exports = (env = {}, argv = {}) => {
const { mode } = argv;
const production = mode === 'production';
const development = !production;

console.log(
    chalk.blue(`The current build process is running in ${chalk.underline((production ? 'production' : 'development').toUpperCase())} mode`)
);

return merge(
    {
        devtool: production ? 'eval' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
    },
    development && {
        optimization: {
            removeAvailableModules: false,
            removeEmptyChunks: false,
            splitChunks: false
        },
        output: {
            pathinfo: false
        }
    },
    {
        context: __dirname,
        target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  //set the entry point to our app(the front-end)
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './front-end/components/Home.tsx'),
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: [
                        'cache-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'ts-loader',
                            options: {
                                transpileOnly: true,
                                happyPackMode: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'eslint-loader',
                            options: {
                                fix: true,
                                quiet: true,
                                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
                                getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [tsNameof] })
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new Dotenv(), new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({ checkSyntacticErrors: true })],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
            plugins: [
                new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
                    configFile: 'tsconfig.json'
                })
            ]
  },
  // output set's the path for front-end bundle file
        output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'front-end/dist'),
            filename: 'home.js'

        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'front-end/dist'),
            compress: true,
            open: true,
            hot: true,
            port: PORT || 3000
        }
    }
);
 };
```

So I expect webpack to bundle my files(which will include everything my Home.tsx uses) in the `front-end/dist` directory under the name `home.js`

here  is how I setup my `Home`. I have a index html at the  path `front-end/index.html` that contains:

```
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script src="/front-end/dist/home.js"></script>
</body>
```

AND  my Home.jsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const ROOT = document.querySelector('.container');
ReactDOM.render(<h1>HELLO 2</h1>, ROOT);
```

When I run `npm run script start` and  open localhost:3000, I get  my browser  showing  me all the files in the `front-end/dist` directory, which is the  `home.js` file. Shouldn't it  load the  Home.tsx  file because  that is what I have  set as the entry point in webpack. How do I configure  webpack to display 'home.tsx' at the  root i.e  localhost:3000.

plus  here my tsconfig file:

```
 {
"compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": ["node_modules/*"],
        "@ruler": ["src", "packages"],
        "@ruler/*": ["src/*", "packages/*"],
        "@ruler/configs": ["configs"],
        "@ruler/configs/*": ["configs/*"],
        "@ruler/test": ["test"],
        "@ruler/test/*": ["test/*"],
        "@ruler/types": ["types"],
        "@ruler/types/*": ["types/*"]
    }
},
"exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

file structure:

```
 Project
       |
       +-- package.json
       |    
       +-- tsconfig.json
       |   
       +-- webpack.config.js
       |   
       +-- front-end 
       |           |  
                   +-- components
                   |            |
                   |             +-- Home.tsx
                   |
                   +--index.html
```

Note: these  are only the  files used for the set-up, the project consists of more  but I don't  they're needed to be mentioned

Comment: It's  Home.tsx, I  have mentioned  it above  when I explained about  setting webpack's `entry` attribute.

Comment: Then you should check the file's extension is it `Home.jsx`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are referring to a wrong file. Because you have mentioned a `.tsx` file but your actual file is a `.jsx` file. So i feel you should add `.jsx` instead:

```
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './front-end/components/Home.jsx')
```

or you should rename your file to ***Home.tsx***.

Comment: It's  named Home.tsx, plus if  it's was  a  naming  error then webpack would have thrown error that file `home.tsx` not  found.

Comment: Right. please check the other answer by reemy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need to add typescript support to your webpack config you need to add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions abd add a specific loader rule for ts files support.

```
 resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
```

your home.js is the bundled file generated by webpack as an output after transpiling your entry file which will be either your Home.jsx or your Home.tsx.

Comment: Don't forget to install the required node dependencies : npm install --save-dev typescript ts-loader source-map-loader

Comment: So my webpack does  have Typescript support  and  i have  installed  dependencies, i ran npm run script build before  running npm run script start.

Comment: can you hand us your files structure?

Comment: I have  shared  the  file structure

Comment: Ok then, you have to add a dist folder under your front-end folder and move your index.html under the dist directory

Comment: but the dist folder doesn't exist, IT'S created  by transpiler. It exist but it is hidden because only  webpack uses  it to attach the  bundle file and it shouldn't  be touched.

Comment: I don't think that's how webpack works , dist folder isn't automatically generated by webpack you create your own entry/output files and folders structure and pass it to webpack within its configuration to enable it recognize your file source and targets and in your case you need to add dist directory it shouldn't be hidden though then put your html file there this is the correct way when I read your webpack config

Comment: `front-end/dist` is the  output path where  webpack will generate our bundle file(in this case our home.js). this a simple setup guide that I'm trying  to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvHB7XZUqO0&list=PLiKs97d-BatHEeclprFtCaw8RcNOYXUqN&index=2. It's 12  mins  long and it does the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but for the tuto example the index.html is put on the project root folder not like your case under a sub folder if you do follow the video you'll be able to get the right output with minimal webpack config just because your html file is present on the project root folder so again either you change your project file structure or change your webpack config !